# database loaded empty after app crashes

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm experiencing a weird problem with my SQLite Database. When I instantiate my `OpenHelper` the first time I launch my app, my database is loaded normally and I can retrieve all my data. If the app crashes, the android manager re-pop my app on my first activity. So all the initialization process is the same, but for some reasons the database is loaded without any data.

Here's my `OpenHelper` constructors:

```
   public static AppDatabaseHelper getInstance(Context ctx, Handler uiHandler, String companyName){
    if(mInstanceWithHandler==null){
        DATABASENAME=companyName;
        mInstanceWithHandler=new AppDatabaseHelper(ctx);
    }
    return mInstanceWithHandler;
    }

    private AppDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASENAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
    }
```

And my `datasource`

```
 public AppDataSource(Context context, Handler handler, String companyName) {
    dbHelper = AppDatabaseHelper.getInstance(context, handler, companyName);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
    this.context = context;
}
```

I really can figure out why the same database is loaded but without any data after the app crashes. Is it handled by the system layer?

EDIT: onCreate/onUpgrade

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // build new tables
    db.execSQL(createSupplier(SUPPLIERS_TABLENAME));
    db.execSQL(createProduct(PRODUCTS_TABLENAME));
    db.execSQL(createUser(USERS_TABLENAME));
    ....
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(final SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
        int newVersion) {

            // Create new tables with temp name
            db.execSQL(createSupplier(SUPPLIERS_TABLENAME + "_temp"));
            ....
            // insert data from old to new tables
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                    "select tbl_name from sqlite_master ", null);
            List<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
                while (cursor.moveToNext())
            ....


            // rename new tables
            db.execSQL("alter table "
                    + AppDatabaseHelper.SUPPLIERS_TABLENAME + "_temp"
                    + " rename to " + SUPPLIERS_TABLENAME);
           ....

}
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace and sqlite open helper `onCreate()` / `onUpgrade()` callbacks.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no stacktrace(no errors) the database is loaded normally I can even save data on it but if I force the App to stop(from task manager) then I lose the data(supposed to be saved after the crash) and I get my normal data back...

Comment: So where and how are you saving the data that gets lost?